# When the app starts - how is the default timezone set? (Nativescript)

Tags: nativescript

When the app starts - how is the default JVM timezone set?

I assume it get's the device's timezone (where ever they might be) - 
and that's what's returned by TimeZone.getDefault()

I'm not getting that behavior on Android simulator - I went into
phone Settings for Date/time and explicitly set it to mine local.

It's off by 1 hr - almost as it doesn't know about daylight savings.

Comment: Looking into the manual https://docs.nativescript.org/hardware/location it seams to use GPS

Comment: Did you try restarting your app after updating the time zone? Can you show some code, how did you find it's hour off, by creating a date object?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the next function which allows me to get the device timezone.

```
import { isIOS } from '@nativescript/core';

export function getTimeZone(): string {
    if (isIOS) {
        return NSTimeZone.localTimeZone.name;
    } else {
        return java.util.TimeZone.getDefault().getID();
    }
}
```